# How extract data and images from .ttf, .dwg ,.indd, .fm, .pmd, .p65, .ppt, .odt and .xls

Tags: asp.net, adobe, ms-office, tiff, openoffice.org

I want to **extract content (data) as well images** in **asp.net** from the following format given below: "**.ttf, .dwg , .indd, .fm, .pmd, .p65, .ppt, .odt and .xls** "

is there any open source or purchased SDK available?

right now i just have solution for .dwg file..

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 1):

.odt is just a zipped bundle of files. In the bundle you will find the images, and the data in XML format.